# Add a Script to Every Single Page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, chatbot

I  have a Laravel project, but not all pages use the same layout blade template.  I am trying to integrate a chatbot, which is a js file. Examination shows it to basically be just a stylized iframe, with the source being hosted by a third party.

The issue I am having is with maintaining the iframe state and data across pages.  For example, if I open the chatbot window and type something while on page 1, I need to be able to have that iframe maintain it's expanded status and also see the ongoing conversation when I navigate to another page.

The content is supposed to persist across pages, but adding a script to a layout makes it so that the iframe loads a new instance of that script every time a different page loads.

I used local storage to determine open/closed state, but I can't see previous content in the chatbot, as that is all server-side on the third party's end.  Every time a new instance of the chat is instantiated, I lose all the previous chat history.

I checked the Laravel documentation, and am reading on service providers.  However, it seems that I would be able to pass a variable across all views, but don't think I can pass an iframe as well.

Any suggestions? I am using Laravel 5.2 (can't upgrade, as the Laravel version is not my call to make)

Comment: Did you come to a resolution on this? Did you try the answer I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include a subview in each of your different layouts.

```
@include('your.script.bladefile.here')
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer, because it could work in another situation. It didn't work for me, and in the end I was able to get an API from the chatbot dev and do some fiddling to get an imporved solution.